# SQL Server fsync Options

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

PostgreSQL has the option to turn off fsync and synchronous commits (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-wal.html). Does SQL Server has this option somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Sql server doesn't let you turn off synchronous writes to the log file.  If you were able to do so, then you would lose ACID compliance.

If this is a "make it go as fast as possible" scenario, then a better approach is to analyze wait statistics to identify what the bottleneck actually is.  Risking data corruption is never a good idea.

Comment: what if it's a containerised database for use in tests? I don't care about data corruption in this case.